# Extracting URL with domain name

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
http://article.wn.com/view/2010/11/26/IV_drug_policy_feels_HIV_patients_Red_Cross/      http://aidsjournal.com/,www.cfpa.org.cn/page1/page2 , www.youtube.com
http://seattletimes.nwsource.com/html/jerrybrewer/2013517803_brewer25.html   http://www.moortowntoday.co.uk/your-moortown/Yorkshire-Evening-Post-First-for.6038672.jp, www.yorkshireeveningpost.co.uk/business/1/
```

I want to extract the URLs with the domain

```
http://article.wn.com        http://aidsjournal.com,www.cfpa.org.cn, www.youtube.com
http://seattletimes.nwsource.com   http://www.moortowntoday.co.uk, www.yorkshireeveningpost.co.uk
```

I used this script but it gave me the result in only one column:

```
sed  's|\(http://[^/]*/\).*|\1|g' file
```

Any suggestion to apply in all of the URL in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v FS='[ ,]*' -v OFS=', ' '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { match($i, /^(([[:alpha:]]+:[/][/])?[^/]+)/); $i = substr($i, RSTART, RLENGTH) } print }' file
```

Output:

```
http://article.wn.com, http://aidsjournal.com, www.cfpa.org.cn, www.youtube.com
http://seattletimes.nwsource.com, http://www.moortowntoday.co.uk, www.yorkshireeveningpost.co.uk
```

Comment: What about `www.cfpa.org.cn`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I see what you mean. I think I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Through perl,

```
$ perl -ple 's/(?:http:\/\/|www\.)[^\/]*\K[^, ]*//g' file
http://article.wn.com      http://aidsjournal.com,www.cfpa.org.cn , www.youtube.com
http://seattletimes.nwsource.com   http://www.moortowntoday.co.uk, www.yorkshireeveningpost.co.uk
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try awk:

```
awk -F/ '{print $1"//"$3}' file
```

Comment: **sed 's/\ /\n/g' file**

Changes file to one-url per line

Comment: That isnt in your answer though ?

Comment: Why is this answer being upvoted, it is literally the only answer on the page which doesn't work ?

Comment: it's easy and useful for the task. any problems?

Comment: Main one being that it doesn't do what OP asked for in any way ?

Answer (score 0):

Alteration of fesias answer.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="((\n| +),* *|,)";FS="/"}/^http:\/\//{print $1"//"$3;next}{print $1}' file
```

EDIT: Didnt see cfpa

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually care about the white spacing in your output, and you actually don't want the comma at the end of one of the URLs (if you do, how do we separate the commas you want from the ones you don't?):

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:],]+' '{sub(/http:\/\//," "); sub(/\/.*/,""); sub(/ /,"http://")} 1' file
http://article.wn.com
http://aidsjournal.com
www.cfpa.org.cn
www.youtube.com
http://seattletimes.nwsource.com
http://www.moortowntoday.co.uk
www.yorkshireeveningpost.co.uk
```

Comment: It's the common way to create/use strings that cannot appear in input. I need to replace `http://`. Rather than picking some odd string or control char that I HOPE doesn't exist in the input file, I'm creating one. First I convert all `a`s to `aA` so at that point the string `aB` CANNOT exist in the input file. Then I convert all `http://`s to `aB`s, do what I need to do with the `/.*`s, then convert all `aB`s back to `http://`s and finally all `aA`s back to `a`s. In this case I could have used `\n` instead of `aB` but oh well.

Comment: ahh fair enough, didnt think of that

Comment: I updated it to make it simpler for this specific case where there's an RS-constituent character available for the replacement.